# FHIR Query resource missing in Continuous Integration spec

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have detected FHIR Query resource is missing in FHIR Continuous Integration page.

Nevertheless,it´s present in Java implementation in zip library for that branch.

We are using this resource in certain FHIR messaging services which are already implemented: Message Bundles with at least MessageHeader and Query resources.

Will Query be present in DSTU2 or the missing is simply an integration error for documentation?

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Query has been supplanted by the notion of OperationDefinition, though how this is done in the messaging space isn't fully documented yet.  The reference implementations aren't yet fully aligned with the draft specification.  Both of these deficiencies will be corrected before the DSTU ballot opens in April.

Comment: We have developed the FHIR messaging microservices with Query, and now we are beginning to develop clients using this microservices. Do you know some link with info how must we use OperationDefinition in messaging? would it be something similar to a Bundle with MessageHeader and OperationDefinition?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  The documentation is still a little lax, but you can find what exists here: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/operations.html (look towards the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Section 2.1.1.5 here (http://hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR-Develop/search.html) will describe this usecase for you, however this section is not finished yet. It will be based on the way operations are invoked asynchronously (see 2.2.0.5 here http://hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR-Develop/operations.html). This section is also sketchy. I will take this up with Grahame and Lloyd to flesh it out.